# Counting nodes in XSLT whose parent nodes have certain attributes

Tags: xslt, xpath, parent

I have XML like this:

```
<exam>
    <section name="SampleSection1">
        <attributes>
            <variable_name data_type="String" value="SCORE"/>
        </attributes>
        <item name="SampleItem1-1"/>
        <item name="SampleItem1-2"/>
        <item name="SampleItem1-3"/>
    </section>
    <section name="SampleSection2">
        <attributes>
            <variable_name data_type="String" value="NO-SCORE"/>
        </attributes>
        <item name="SampleItem2-1"/>
        <item name="SampleItem2-2"/>
    </section>
</exam>
```

I want to count the number of items that are in a section that has a variable_name of "SCORE".

I thought that this would do the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:variable name="scoredItems"
                  select="./item/../attributes/variable_name[@value='SCORE']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="scoredItemsCount" select="count($scoredItems)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$scoredItemsCount"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this outputs:

```
1
0
```

not

```
3
0
```

which is what I would expect (and want).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     <xsl:variable name="scoredItems" 
>               select="./item/../attributes/variable_name[@value='SCORE']"/>
> ```

This selects all `variable-name` elements such that their `value` attribute has value of `'SCORE'`. And this *is* just one node.

You want:

**`self::section[attributes/variable_name/@value='SCORE']/item`**

This selects all item elements in case the context node (`section`) has an element `attributes` that has an element `variable_name` whose `value` attribute is `'SCORE'.

In case the context node doesn't have that property, then the above XPath expression selects nothing.

**Now the corrected transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:variable name="scoredItems"
                  select="self::section[attributes/variable_name/@value='SCORE']/item"/>
        <xsl:variable name="scoredItemsCount" select="count($scoredItems)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$scoredItemsCount"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
3
0
```